# HTML Page Parts

Tags: html

Is there any way I can measure out my HTML page and then find out 40% of it or 60% of its length, so that certain elements of the page can occupy only that much?

Comment: is the css: `width: 40%` what you are looking for, or is it something else you want?

Comment: No, width would mean horizontal.. I want to measure out 40% or 60% of the length of the page.

Comment: vertically.. that's sort of missing in your question

Comment: Be aware that the length of the page is determined by the amount of content you have in it. If you don't have enough content to fill the browser's viewport `height: 60%` will not give you 60% of the height of the viewport, but 60% of the height of the content container

Comment: so suppose I want to write text for 10% of the page I do : <div style="height: 10%;"> Hello </div>  ?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see what happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(In terms of horizantal aligning) You can achieve such kind of styling/marking-up with 2 div elements and CSS;

```
<!--Your HTML-->
<div id="fortypercent" class="next_to_each_other"></div>
<div id="sixtypercent" class="next_to_each_other"></div>
<!--Ends here-->

/***Your CSS***/
div.next_to_each_other {position:relative; float:left;}
div#fortypercent {width:40%;}
div#sixtypercent {width:60%;}
/***Ends here***/
```

That's all.

(In terms of vertical aligning) You can achieve such kind of styling/marking-up with 2 div elements and CSS, too; this time marking stays the same and styling is as below.

```
/***Your CSS***/
html, body {width:100%; height:100%; margin:0px; padding:0px;}
div.next_to_each_other {position:relative; float:left;}
div#fortypercent {width:100%; height:40%;}
div#sixtypercent {width:100%; height:60%;}
/***Ends here***/
```

You can find out whether it works or not by assigning different background-colors to each div.

Answer (score 1):

yes, with CSS this is quite simple

```
<div style="width: 70%;"> this will take up 70% of your width </div>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. OP want's height, not width.

Comment: ok, height perhaps, (he asked for length), height would probably be better :-) @Jasper yes, just to make it small and simple, inlining css is of course not ideal

Answer (score 0):

This is easy to do, though you need to know JavaScript.

This statement will give "foo" the length of id "bar" in pixels:

```
foo = document.getElementById('bar').offsetHeight;
```

If you then do

```
height1 = foo * 0.4;
height2 = foo * 0.6;
```

you can use it to do

```
document.getElementById('height1').style.height = height1 + 'px';
document.getElementById('height2').style.height = height2 + 'px';
```

Using this method, you can look at the height of an element, and set the height of other elements based on the first element.

Tell me if there is something you want me to add!

Comment: The problem with pure CSS is that the height you are calculating from is being modified by the height. If your HTML-page has a set height, then of course, you could do it, but be aware of the different settings of overflow..